# jQuery animation stutter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Once again I visit for your bountiful knowledge :P

I am developing a small and simple game using jQuery (just as a practice for jQuery). I am trying to stop a bug seems to make the movement stutter on the first move. To replicate this just hold down a direction. It stutters once then moves smoothly after.

The code i am using is:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) { 
case 37:
    $('#move').animate({
        left: '-=2'
    },1); //left arrow key
    break;
case 38:
    $('#move').stop().animate({
        top: '-=20' 
    }).animate({
            top: '+=20'        
    }); //up arrow key (jump)
    break;
case 39:
    $('#move').animate({
        left: '+=2'
    },1); //right arrow key 
    break;

}
});
```

It is probably something very silly like an attribute that I am missing, but I can't quite figure it out.

EDIT: I have tried in various browsers and still get the same problem.

EDIT 2: I have put it on jsfiddle though it doesn't work the same as with my own browser, but it should give you an idea :P  http://jsfiddle.net/urAGB/4/

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle someone will be able to help you.

Comment: It's because when you hold down a key the first input is a bit longer to prevent accidental double clicking of a key, so there's an approx. 500ms delay before it starts repeating.

Comment: yes but is there any way to fix this? i have seen people do what i am trying to do with other jquery games

Answer (score 0):

[heres my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfast2008/urAGB/6/). I only changed the javascript.

its actually kind of complicated to circumvent such an issue, which explains the mass code. so heres a walkthrough:

- a function that auto-moves the object, between the time of keypress and when the key is detected as being 'held down'
- we activate and deactivate this function under certain conditions

i have made it easy for you to tweak this so called **delay until the key is detected as being held down**, by changing the `bufferTimeout` variable. feel free to chuck all the code into a function and even put it in an external javascript file to ease of use.

if it solves your problem, enjoy :)

Comment: you might wanna change it so the left key makes the blue box move left

Comment: cheers for the heads up. if OP has gotten this far in coding, they should know that they can just chuck the code into a function, and pass in an argument. then based on this argument, it will either be `x-=n` or `x+=n` :)

Comment: Thank you micheal for your answer, its appears to work with only one draw back from what i can see. It appears that a single press makes it move much further that intended. any ideas?

Comment: Ah i see why it is happening, no idea how to fix it but its nice to know :P

Comment: Hey, just change bufferTimeout to a smaller value. Feel free to mark this question as answered :D

Comment: But when i change the bufferTimeout to a smaller value the stutter returns.

Comment: [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfast2008/urAGB/7/), and try changing `bufferTimeout` in increments of 0.25. this should get it quite close to what you want - let me know how it goes.

Comment: That work okish at around 7. Thank for your help pal! really appreciated. Im going to leave this open until tomorrow to see if anyone else has any ideas though.

Comment: No worries, sorry i couldn't help